# StackTrello - add a 'trello' link to create cards from Questions

Tags: app, script

I wrote a script to create trello cards from questions on SE sites.  This was really for me more than anything else because I use trello to help me keep track of things I'm working on, which sometimes include feature requests and bugs raised on MSO.  An auth redirection will happen the first time you try to use it, but after that it should work as you would expect.  Formatting is preserved, and cards can be created on any of your boards and can be given a (single) label.

See the [demo video](http://youtu.be/AUJ27ISlTVI) for usage.

The script can be found here: https://gist.github.com/aggieben/5811685

[Click to install](https://gist.github.com/aggieben/5811685/raw/stacktrello.user.js).

Answer (score 2):

When I try to install this, it gives me "Invalid script head".

I've compared to other userscripts but haven't found the problem.

I'm running Chrome 28 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Did you try to install it as a native chrome extension, or using Tampermonkey?

Comment: I tried natively.

Comment: It will only work with a Greasemonkey-compatible extension because Chrome doesn't support all the GM_* functions or headers I'm using.  In Chrome, you'll have to use Tampermonkey.  If I get time I may see if there's a way to make it more portable by not using GM_* functions, but for now I don't think t here's a way around it.